# React component responsible for receiving data from a product and rendering it is rendered before the data arrives

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am taking a React course in which week by week we have certain challenges that lead us to create an E-Commerce.
My problem is that, I have the data of a product hardcoded, when entering the page useEffect creates a promise that is resolved in 2 seconds using setTimeOut and returns the product data.

In a previous challenge I already did essentially the same thing, only having an array with several products and following the design pattern of: **ItemListContainer** asks for the data, passes the data to **ItemList**, applies *.map()* to the array and for each item creates an **Item** component sending by props the data.

In the current challenge as we are working with a single product we do not have to do .map() on any array, and this for some reason causes the Item component (in this case called **ItemDetail**) to render before the data arrives, although it only renders the parts that do not depend on the data arriving to it.

Demo: [Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuNwP.gif) (It renders the styled div and the "$" sign).

After several hours looking at the code I can't figure out why it happens and what I could do to fix it.

**Github repo:** [enzom-uy/coderhouseECommerce](https://github.com/enzom-uy/coderhouseECommerce-munioz)

**ItemDetailContainer code:**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ItemDetail from '../ItemDetail/ItemDetail'

const productData = {
  id: '4',
  name: 'Cuarto producto',
  description: 'Descripcion del cuarto producto',
  price: 10,
  pictureUrl:
    'https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/thumbnail-image-vector-graphic-vector-id1147544807?k=20&m=1147544807&s=612x612&w=0&h=pBhz1dkwsCMq37Udtp9sfxbjaMl27JUapoyYpQm0anc='
}

const ItemDetailContainer = () => {
  const [detailedProduct, setDetailedProduct] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchingData = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        res(productData)
      }, 2000)
    })
    fetchingData.then((res) => {
      setDetailedProduct(res)
      console.log('Se guardaron los datos')
    })
    fetchingData.catch((err) => {
      console.log('Failed')
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Producto detallado</h1>
      <ItemDetail product={detailedProduct} />
    </>
  )
}

export default ItemDetailContainer
```

**ItemDetail code:**

```js
import React from 'react'

export default function ItemDetail({ product }) {
  return (
    <div className="bg-slate-100 w-60 flex flex-col items-center mx-1 px-2 border border-slate-400 text-center">
      <span>{product.name}</span>
      <img src={product.pictureUrl} width="120" />
      <p>{product.description}</p>
      <span>${product.price}</span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Short Answer**

It is showing the styled div and the dollar sign because that is what you have included in the JSX. To remove it until the data arrives, you can make it a part of the return statement conditionally on the data being present. That might look something like this (using the simpler of the options listed later in my answer)

```js
return (
  <>
    <h1>Producto detallado</h1>
    {detailedProduct.name && <ItemDetail product={detailedProduct} />}
  </>
)
```

**Why It's Happening**

If you have a simple component that doesn't rely on data, then it will render everything in the return statement. In the below example, that is the `div`, `h1`, and `p` element.

```js
function Parent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
      <p>We have no products to sell.</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you have a component that does rely on data, say from an API (or a setTimeout), then that doesn't change. What is included in the return statement (including any child components) will be rendered.

```js
function Parent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.com')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(setData)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
      <Child data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({ data }) {
  return (
    <p>The name is: {data.name}</p>
  );
}
```

In this case, before the data comes back from the API, the child element's `<p>` element with the text "The name is: " will appear, since it is a part of the return. Then, when the data arrives, it will re-render and the name will appear. If we want it to say something else, we can do that with something like this...

```js
function Child({ data }) {
  return (
    <p>{data.name ? `The name is: ${data.name}` : "Loading name..."}</p>
  );
}
```

This will ask the component, "is there a value for the `data.name` property? If yes, then display the text "The name is: ___" where the name is filled in the blank. If no, then display the text "Loading name..."

**This is also option 1 for your solution.** You can use a ternary operator to provide a default value when the data has not yet arrived.

Another option is to just remove the entire component that relies on the data. Since the return statement will only return items that are truth-y, you can conditionally render your ItemDetail component. Our example might look something like this...

```js
function Parent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.com')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(setData)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
      {data.name && <Child data={data} />}
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({ data }) {
  return (
    <p>The name is: {data.name}</p>
  );
}
```

**This is option 2 for your solution.** It is quick and easy, but there are distinct differences between how they impact developer and user experience.

**As an option 3**, you could also implement a loading component that would take the place of the product component (including something like a spinner or progress bar), but I think it may be more work than your React course calls for.

**Important Note.** While the second option is definitely *easier* since you don't have to code default values for every field, it can sometimes be *worse* for user experience, since entire components will appear and disappear when data loads in, which can cause big layout shifts.

Comment: Thanks! That was a great explanation. I'm going to stick with the first option since I have to stay within the task given in the exercise, but all the options seemed excellent!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a few things like:

1. Don't render your component until the request is done or...
2. Use loading flag state

Use an extra state for the "loading" flag.. you can start this on "true" and after finished change it to false and render your component with the data.

This is my example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const productData = {
    id: "4",
    name: "Cuarto producto",
    description: "Descripcion del cuarto producto",
    price: 10,
    pictureUrl:
        "https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/thumbnail-image-vector-graphic-vector-id1147544807?k=20&m=1147544807&s=612x612&w=0&h=pBhz1dkwsCMq37Udtp9sfxbjaMl27JUapoyYpQm0anc="
};

const ItemDetailContainer = () => {
    const [detailedProduct, setDetailedProduct] = useState({});
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchingData = new Promise((res, rej) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                res(productData);
            }, 2000);
        });
        fetchingData.then((res) => {
            setDetailedProduct(res);
            setLoading(false);
            console.log("Se guardaron los datos");
        });
        fetchingData.catch((err) => {
            console.log("Failed");
        });
    }, []);

    if (loading) return "Cargando...";

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Producto detallado</h1>
            <ItemDetail product={detailedProduct} />
        </>
    );
};

export default ItemDetailContainer;

function ItemDetail({ product }) {
    return (
        <div className="bg-slate-100 w-60 flex flex-col items-center mx-1 px-2 border border-slate-400 text-center">
            <span>{product.name}</span>
            <img src={product.pictureUrl} width="120" />
            <p>{product.description}</p>
            <span>${product.price}</span>
        </div>
    );
}
```